# Why can I see a font even if it is not installed

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts

I do not have **Seravek** font installed on my system. My client sent a Microsoft Word document with contents using this font. When I select the text, it shows the correct font name i.e. Seravek.

However, I cannot find a corresponding font file *(seravek.ttf)* anywhere. I've looked at `C:\Windows\Fonts` and also searched in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\`

Can anyone help me to understand: If the font is not installed on my system, how can I still see that font?

Comment: try renaming the extension from `.docx` to `.zip` and search inside

Comment: @AEonAX, that was interesting.. it revealed the xml files. However, the font file was not in that list.

Comment: Does it merely show the correct font name in the style toolbar, or does it show that name **and** [render the font](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/processtype/seravek/)?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If somebody sends you a Word document using a font that isn't installed on your computer, and they don't embed the font in the document, then Word will replace the font you don't have (Seravek in your case) with a default you do have (possibly Calibri, Arial or Times New Roman depending on your setup).

Confusingly, when you select the text and look at what font is being displayed, Word still says 'Seravek' (the name of the font you don't have).

Your options are:

1. Try and install the font yourself. [Seravek requires a license](https://processtypefoundry.com/fonts/seravek/).
2. Ask the person sending the document to [embed the font in Word](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/35082/word-2013-embed-fonts-in-a-document/) (as Thomas Weinbrenner suggests)
3. Ask the person to save the file as a static PDF which will embed the fonts automatically, but you won't be able to edit it in that format.

Comment: Adobe applications have a couple of fallback fonts they can use when the requested font is not installed or embedded. Each character is adjusted so it takes the same width as the original font, and it tries to match the boldness too.

Answer (score 13):

It is possible to [embed fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_embedding) in documents.

So if this document uses a font which is not installed on your system, then this is probably a font embedded in this word document.

Comment: Is it anyway possible to find the ttf file?

Comment: Have you verified it is specifically possible to embed fonts into Microsoft Word documents though?  I originally thought you were correct, as I thought about it again, I had second thoughts.  Which is the reason I want documented evidence you can embed fonts into Microsoft Word documents.

Comment: You can embed fonts in Word documents, but it doesn't happen automatically, you have to [go out of your way](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/35082/word-2013-embed-fonts-in-a-document/) to do this.

Comment: See the linked Wikipedia article: `Font embedding is the inclusion of font files inside an electronic document. This has been possible with Portable Document Format (PDF), Microsoft Word for Windows and some other applications for many years.`

Comment: @ThomasWeinbrenner - You should include how the font is embedded into the documents, into the answer itself as the link(s) have, relevant information which help support your answer..

Comment: [How to embed a TrueType font in a document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/290952)

Comment: [Export font from Word 2010](http://superuser.com/q/290845) to extract the embedded font.

Comment: Note that while it may be possible to extract an embedded font from a document, that doesn't mean you have the legal right to use that font. Even embedding itself is considered a copyright violation by some vendors.

Answer (score -1):

In your situation, it might be embedded.

Try making a Word file and see if you find Seravek in the Font Combo Box.

If it cannot be found the font would be embedded.

Comment: Please try not to start every word with a capital letter.